# JSTL - Exists the remove-attribute for put-list-attribute?

Tags: java, jstl, tiles, apache-tiles

I have the following code for my main tile definition:

```
<definition name="main" template="/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/main/template.jsp">
    ...
    <put-list-attribute name="jsBase">
        <add-attribute value="basics" />
        <add-attribute value="jquery" />
    </put-list-attribute>
    <put-list-attribute name="jsExtra">
        <add-attribute value="boostrap" />
        <add-attribute value="d3" />
        <add-attribute value="gridster" />
        <add-attribute value="custom" />
    </put-list-attribute>
</definition>
```

This definition will be used for all the pages. `template.jsp` looks like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles-extras" prefix="tilesx" %>
...

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="html">
    <head>
    ...

    <tilesx:useAttribute id="jsBase" name="jsBase" classname="java.util.List" />
    <c:forEach var="file" items="${jsBase}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/${file}.js"/>" />
    </c:forEach>

    <tilesx:useAttribute id="jsExtra" name="jsExtra" classname="java.util.List" />
    <c:forEach var="file" items="${jsExtra}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/${file}.js"/>" />
    </c:forEach>
    ...
```

The idea is to load all files defined in `jsBase` and `jsExtra`, taking into consideration that I will keep `jsBase` untouched for all pages but `jsExtra` can vary from page to page. I know there exists the inheratance property that can add extra values to a list or override it with new values, but what I want is to inherit all values from the original list AND remove just one value, so I don't have to define again the values I want to keep from the original list. It's possible to do something like this?:

```
    <put-list-attribute name="jsExtra" inherit="true">
        <remove-attribute value="custom" />
    </put-list-attribute>
```

In case it's impossible to use something like, some workaround to prevent duplicated code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks John Lee for your answer. But there is little problem: `template.jsp` is loaded for every page, and I want to exclude `custom.js` for specific pages, not all pages (if it were the case then I wouldn't include `custom.js` in `jsExtra` in ther first place).
But taking your idea as inspiration I came accross to this solution:

```
<tilesx:useAttribute id="jsExclude" name="jsExclude" classname="java.util.List" />
<tilesx:useAttribute id="jsExtra" name="jsExtra" classname="java.util.List"/>
<c:forEach var="file" items="${jsExtra}">
    <c:if test="${!jsExclude.contains(file)}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/${file}.js"/>"></script>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Quick explanation: I defined a exclusion list which contains the files names I don't want to load for each page I define in my tiles files. That way I can inherit all values contained in `jsExtra` from my main definition and select the values that I want to exclude.

Answer (score 1):

According to the needs "inherit all values from the original list AND remove just one value ", if the script file is what you wanna exclude, then don't show it in the page.

```
<c:forEach var="file" items="${jsExtra}">
    <c:if test="${file != 'custom'}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="<c:url value="/js/${file}.js"/>" />
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.

Comment: @Korcholis I use this copy-pasted comment for such cases. Take it if you like.

Comment: Thanks @peterh, however it's the automatic comment paster upon revision. Good point, indeed

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: Sorry, my english is poor, I'm trying.

Comment: Thanks for the idea! The code as it is now works but not in the most efficient way... still it served me as inspiration :D